# Find all the same numbers in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with numbers in the range of 0 - 100. I need to find all the same numbers and add 1 to them.

my code worked well with arrays like [100, 2, 1, 1, 0]

```
const findAndChangeDuplicates = (arr: any) => {
    for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (arr[i + 1] === arr[i] && arr[i] <= 5) {
            arr[i] += 1;
        } else if (arr[i - 1] === arr[i] && arr[i] >= 5) {
            arr[i] -= 1;

            findAndChangeDuplicates(arr);
        }
    }

    return arr;
};
```

but when I came across this
[100, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0]

my code let me down.

Expected Result:
[100, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]

Have any ideas?

Comment: please add the wanted result of the given array after calling the function.

Comment: What do you mean, *find all same numbers and add 1 to them*? Please explain.

Comment: Welcome to SO, but this question is pretty vague.  What does *"I need to find all the same numbers and add 1 to them"* mean?  What are the same numbers?  And what do you specifically mean by "my code let me down"?  What output were you expecting?

Comment: with 6, 6, 6, if the code reaches the second 6 it decreases it, so there is 6, 5, 6, and thus the third 6 doesnt change.

Comment: You are only comparing for two index  - Any duplicates more than 2 get not considered

Comment: `[...new Set(arr)].map(i => i+1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An approach by using at least one loop from the end to adjust the values and if necessary another loop from the beginning to set the largest value to `100`.

Both loops feature a value variable `v`. In the first loop, it starts with the last value of the array and increments its value and check is the item is smaller than this value.

If smaller, then the value is assigned, otherwise the actual value is taken for the next item.

if necessary, the other loop works in opposite direction and with a start value of `100` and checks if the item is greater than wanted and takes the smaller value, or the value is taken from the item.

The result is an array which has a gereatest value of `100` at start and goes until zero or greater to the end of the array.

```js
function update(array) {
    var i = array.length,
        v = array[--i];

    while (i--) if (array[i] < ++v) array[i] = v; else v = array[i];
    if (array[0] > 100) {
        v = 100;
        for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] > v) array[i] = v; else v = array[i];
            v--;
        }
    }
    return array;
}

console.log(update([100, 2, 1, 1, 0]));
console.log(update( [100, 100, 99, 86, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0]))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This only works as long as the array is ordered, right?

Comment: right, the given data looks ordered. if not, then an other approach is necessary.

Comment: Yup, that's a beautiful solution anyway, efficient and straightforward, as always :p.

Comment: @NinaScholz I think this solves my question. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a forEach on your array to do this, using the 3rd parameter of the callback, the array itself, and a bit of recursivity

```
const increment_to_unicity = (value, index, self) => {
    if (self.indexOf(value) !== index) {
        self[index]++
        increment_to_unicity(self[index], index, self)
    }
    return self[index];
}
arr = arr.map(increment_to_unicity).sort((a, b) => b - a);
```

Comment: I added a sort function at the end of the call to reorder the array, is it fixing it ?

Comment: Good, this work for me with this condition

if (self [index]> = 95) {
     self [index] -
    increment_to_unicity (self [index], index, self);
}

Answer (score 1):

The following assumes you want them ordered from highest to lowest, if not this might ba as well as useless to you.

The idea is to first create an Object to keep track of how many of each number exist. We then map each value by first checking whether it's unique and if not increasing it until we can't find any value inside the Object anymore. This will not neatly order the numbers by itself so we will have to sort afterwards.

```js
let arr1 = [100, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    arr2 = [100, 2, 1, 1, 0];

const f = (arr) => arr.reduce((a,c) => (a[c] = (a[c] || 0) + 1, a),{}),
      g = (arr, obj) => arr.map(v => {
        if (obj[v] > 1) {
          let i = 1;
          obj[v] = obj[v] - 1;
          while (obj[v + i]) {
            i++;
          }
          obj[v + i] = (obj[v + i] || 0) + 1;
          return v + i;
        } else {
          return v;
        }
      }).sort((a,b) => +b - +a);

console.log(g(arr1, f(arr1)))
console.log(g(arr2, f(arr2)))
```

Comment: Not a bad decision, but if there is an array [100, 100, 100, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]

there should be a result [100, 99, 98, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a verbose solution that will work with unordered arrays as well.
It's not efficient, neither brilliant, but it takes care of unordered arrays as well.

Basically, it takes advantage of `reduce` to collect all the occurrences of each element. Each time it finds more than one, it increases all the occurrences by 1 **except the last one**.

Next, it checks whether there still are duplicates. If there are, it repeats the process until none is found. Of course, it's not the cleverest approach, but it works.

---

```js
// Increases all duplicates until there are no more duplicates.
const increaseDuplicates = (arr, index) => {
  // Repeat the code until no duplicate is found
  while (!noDuplicates(arr)) {
    // Acquire all the occurrences of each item, keeping track of the index.
    Object.entries(arr.reduce((acc, next, i) => {
      acc[next] = acc[next] || [];
      return acc[next].push(i), acc;
    }, {})).forEach(([n, indexes]) => {
      // for each value found, check whether it appears at least twice.
      if (indexes.length > 1) {
        // if it does, increase the value of every item but the last one.
        for (var i = 0; i < indexes.length - 1; i++) {
          arr[indexes[i]]++;
        }
      }
    });
  }
  return arr;
};
// Asserts an array has no duplicates.
const noDuplicates = (arr) => [...new Set(arr)].length === arr.length;


const input = [100, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0];
console.log(increaseDuplicates(input));
const unorderedInput = [6,4,5,6,6,6,6,5,6,3,1,2,3,99,403,100, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0];
console.log(increaseDuplicates(unorderedInput));
```

Comment: Not a bad decision, but if there is an array [100, 100, 100, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0] there should be a result [100, 99, 98, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

Comment: @Grigri Oh, I didn't see the "0 - 100" rule, it was not that evident in the first place :P. Give me a moment, I will alter my example later to address the issue :)

Comment: @Grigri, that is an important information. you might add it to the question.

Comment: @NinaScholz I actually didn't see that, it was at the very beginning of the question. Not sure whether it was added, but I didn't put enough attention to it, I just saw the example and went straightforward on it.

Comment: ther is no hint that the values could be not greater than 100 or smaller than zero. but anyway.

Comment: @NinaScholz wops, you're right, it says the array has range [0-100], though it doesn't mean it should decrease value in case of 100, indeed.

Comment: @NinaScholz Sorry, but I mean the range of 0 - 100 is no more and no less.